# Why can't send the correct data with sockets? JAVA (Client-Server Program running on local)

Tags: java, sockets, io, client-server

i'm trying to make a server client program in java. I'm trying to run on same system. It sends a text file from client to server including names etc. But when the server gets the file it just prints "[]" characters. Does that mean null or does that mean corrupted data?

Here is the server;

```
package temel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class VeriAlma {

  private static int port;

  private static Socket socket;
  public VeriAlma(int port)
  {
      VeriAlma.port=port;
  }
  public static void veriAl() {
    try {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);

                socket = listener.accept(); 

    }
    catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
  }

  public String run() {
    try {
      InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();


        String file_name = "x.txt";

        File file=new File(file_name);

        ByteStream.toFile(in, file);
      return file_name;
    }
    catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
      return "asdasd";
    }
  }
  public void setPort(int port)
  {
      VeriAlma.port=port;

  }
}
```

Here is the client

```
package temel;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.net.Socket;

public class VeriGonderme {

      // host and port of receiver
      private static int    port;
      private static String host;

      public VeriGonderme(int port,String host)
      {
          this.port=port;
          this.host=host;
      }
      public void veriGonder(String dosyaIsmi) {
        try {
          Socket       socket = new Socket(host, port);
          OutputStream os     = socket.getOutputStream();


          ByteStream.toStream(os, 1);


            ByteStream.toStream(os, dosyaIsmi);
            ByteStream.toStream(os, new File(dosyaIsmi));
          }catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
      public void setPort(int port)
      {
          this.port=port;

      }
      public void setHost(String host)
      {
          this.host=host;

      }

      }
```

host is "localhost" port is 4444

[This is the original code i modified it a little bit](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/blog/2004/november/15.html)

Comment: Can you print out the values you are sending and the values you read?

Comment: one more question. Do i need to repeat listener.accept() line or is this okay? By the way thank you for your interest.

Comment: You need to repeat accept() if you have more than one connection (ever)

Answer (score 0):

> But when the server gets the file it just prints "[]" characters.

I would expect to see some characters like this because you are sending the value `1` as a 4 byte binary. i.e. `\0\0\0\u0001`  If you remove this and only send the file once, it may do as you expected.

Comment: Ok i'll give it a try. But i didn't quite get the idea of repeating. I will send only one file but don't know when i will send it. I mean does "accept" opens the port and waits for data? Or does it accept data exactly when the line is processed? Sorry for word crowd.

Comment: You are calling toStream three times when you are only expecting a files's contents. accept() waits on an port you are listening to already and wait for a new connection. When you read the data, it wait for some data.